# PostgreSQL 12 - Using both Similarity an ts_query at the same time, better performance?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Running a query with `similarity` or `ts_query` only or running them `AND'ded` together, the performance is good but the results aren't optimal for real time search.

We use both similarity and ts_query in combination to produce desirable results as with ts_query one character off and you get zero results. Similarity is good but produces odd results when words are simply present in others.

There are only 60k rows in the table, so scaling this up seems terrifying for a product where search is important.

**Query in question (with OR)**

```
    SELECT 
  ts_rank("products_displayproduct"."search_index", to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'WowWee:*'), 8) AS "rank", 
  ("products_displayproduct"."name" <-> 'WowWee') AS "similarity",
  "products_displayproduct"."id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
  "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
  "products_displayproduct"."name", 
  "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
  "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
  "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
  "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
  "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
  "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
  "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
  "products_displayproduct"."search_index"
FROM 
  "products_displayproduct" 
  INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
    "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
  ) 
WHERE 
 "products_displayproductaccess"."location_intspace" IN (758, 759) 
  AND "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1511, 940, 931, 660, 661) 
  AND (
    ("products_displayproduct"."search_index") @@ (to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'WowWee:*'))
    OR "products_displayproduct"."name" % 'WowWee'
  )
ORDER BY 
  "rank" DESC, 
  "products_displayproduct"."id" ASC
LIMIT 100
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE (with OR)**

```
Limit  (cost=19376.51..19401.51 rows=100 width=720) (actual time=586.733..586.741 rows=51 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=19376.51..19535.76 rows=637 width=720) (actual time=586.730..586.734 rows=51 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (ts_rank(products_displayproduct.search_index, '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery, 8)) DESC, products_displayproduct.id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 39kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=132.72..16941.94 rows=637 width=720) (actual time=141.764..586.618 rows=51 loops=1)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products_displayproduct  (cost=90.22..250.21 rows=103 width=712) (actual time=141.562..585.014 rows=51 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((search_index @@ '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery) OR ((name)::text % 'WowWee'::text))
                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 51994
                    Heap Blocks: exact=1554
                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=90.22..90.22 rows=103 width=0) (actual time=49.036..49.036 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_di_search__a06b26_gist  (cost=0.00..41.86 rows=51 width=0) (actual time=12.531..12.531 rows=52055 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (search_index @@ '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_displayproduct_name_gist  (cost=0.00..43.21 rows=52 width=0) (actual time=36.502..36.502 rows=2 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((name)::text % 'WowWee'::text)
              ->  Append  (cost=42.50..158.89 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.020 rows=1 loops=51)
                    ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_758_product_id_idx on products_displayproductaccess_758  (cost=42.50..85.14 rows=5 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=51)
                          Index Cond: (product_id = products_displayproduct.id)
                          Filter: ((location_intspace = ANY ('{758,759}'::integer[])) AND (location_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,1511,940,931,660,661}'::integer[])))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                    ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_759_product_id_idx on products_displayproductaccess_759  (cost=42.25..73.72 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=51)
                          Index Cond: (product_id = products_displayproduct.id)
                          Filter: ((location_intspace = ANY ('{758,759}'::integer[])) AND (location_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,1511,940,931,660,661}'::integer[])))
Planning Time: 3.988 ms
Execution Time: 586.878 ms
```

**Query in question (with AND)**

```
    SELECT 
  ts_rank("products_displayproduct"."search_index", to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'WowWee:*'), 8) AS "rank", 
  ("products_displayproduct"."name" <-> 'WowWee') AS "similarity",
  "products_displayproduct"."id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
  "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
  "products_displayproduct"."name", 
  "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
  "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
  "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
  "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
  "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
  "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
  "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
  "products_displayproduct"."search_index"
FROM 
  "products_displayproduct" 
  INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
    "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
  ) 
WHERE 
 "products_displayproductaccess"."location_intspace" IN (758, 759) 
  AND "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1511, 940, 931, 660, 661) 
  AND (
    ("products_displayproduct"."search_index") @@ (to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'WowWee:*'))
    AND "products_displayproduct"."name" % 'WowWee'
  )
ORDER BY 
  "rank" DESC, 
  "products_displayproduct"."id" ASC
LIMIT 100
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE (with AND)**

```
 Limit  (cost=283.32..284.82 rows=6 width=720) (actual time=43.936..43.937 rows=2 loops=1)
      ->  Sort  (cost=283.32..284.82 rows=6 width=720) (actual time=43.935..43.935 rows=2 loops=1)
            Sort Key: (ts_rank(products_displayproduct.search_index, '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery, 8)) DESC, products_displayproduct.id
            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=70.25..275.57 rows=6 width=720) (actual time=4.057..43.921 rows=2 loops=1)
                  ->  Index Scan using products_di_search__a06b26_gist on products_displayproduct  (cost=27.75..111.22 rows=1 width=712) (actual time=4.025..43.858 rows=2 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (search_index @@ '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery)
                        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 51994
                        Filter: ((name)::text % 'WowWee'::text)
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 49
                  ->  Append  (cost=42.50..161.28 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.022 rows=1 loops=2)
                        ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_758_product_id_idx on products_displayproductaccess_758  (cost=42.50..86.39 rows=5 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=2)
                              Index Cond: (product_id = products_displayproduct.id)
                              Filter: ((location_intspace = ANY ('{758,759}'::integer[])) AND (location_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,1511,940,931,660,661}'::integer[])))
                              Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                        ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_759_product_id_idx on products_displayproductaccess_759  (cost=42.25..74.86 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=2)
                              Index Cond: (product_id = products_displayproduct.id)
                              Filter: ((location_intspace = ANY ('{758,759}'::integer[])) AND (location_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,1511,940,931,660,661}'::integer[])))
    Planning Time: 1.793 ms
    Execution Time: 43.991 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a GIN index for full text search, that usually performs better. You are killed by the many false positive results of the index scan.

Comment: Will give it a go and replace the GiST index with a GIN one on the search_index (ts_vector) column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Laurenz! That plus the following re-written query made things go from 586ms to 17ms.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
  ts_rank("products_displayproduct"."search_index", to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'WowWee:*'), 8) AS "rank", 
  ("products_displayproduct"."name" <-> 'WowWee') AS "similarity",
  "products_displayproduct"."id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
  "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
  "products_displayproduct"."name", 
  "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
  "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
  "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
  "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
  "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
  "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
  "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
  "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
  "products_displayproduct"."search_index"
FROM 
  "products_displayproduct" 
WHERE 
   (
    ("products_displayproduct"."search_index") @@ (to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', 'WowWee:*'))
    OR "products_displayproduct"."name" % 'WowWee'
  )
  ORDER BY "rank" DESC
) products_displayproduct
  JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
    "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_id"
     AND "products_displayproductaccess"."location_intspace" IN (758, 759) 
     AND "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1511, 940, 931, 660, 661) 
  ) 
LIMIT 100
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

```
Limit  (cost=1730.13..1734.13 rows=100 width=1862) (actual time=16.701..17.308 rows=51 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1730.13..71972.05 rows=1754686 width=1862) (actual time=16.699..17.269 rows=51 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=1729.70..1732.43 rows=1092 width=1646) (actual time=16.671..16.693 rows=51 loops=1)
              Sort Key: (ts_rank(products_displayproduct.search_index, '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery, 8)) DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 39kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products_displayproduct  (cost=41.02..1674.59 rows=1092 width=1646) (actual time=16.284..16.615 rows=51 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((search_index @@ '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery) OR ((name)::text % 'WowWee'::text))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=37
                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=41.02..41.02 rows=1093 width=0) (actual time=16.251..16.252 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_di_search__fecb92_gin  (cost=0.00..31.81 rows=1041 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=51 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (search_index @@ '''wowwe'':*'::tsquery)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_displayproduct_name_gist  (cost=0.00..8.67 rows=52 width=0) (actual time=16.226..16.227 rows=4 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((name)::text % 'WowWee'::text)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.42..64.21 rows=10 width=216) (actual time=0.006..0.009 rows=1 loops=51)
              ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_758_product_id_idx on products_displayproductaccess_758  (cost=0.42..39.26 rows=8 width=216) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=51)
                    Index Cond: (product_id = products_displayproduct.id)
                    Filter: ((location_intspace = ANY ('{758,759}'::integer[])) AND (location_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,1511,940,931,660,661}'::integer[])))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 3
              ->  Index Scan using products_displayproductaccess_759_product_id_idx on products_displayproductaccess_759  (cost=0.42..24.90 rows=2 width=217) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=51)
                    Index Cond: (product_id = products_displayproduct.id)
                    Filter: ((location_intspace = ANY ('{758,759}'::integer[])) AND (location_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,1511,940,931,660,661}'::integer[])))
Planning Time: 0.713 ms
Execution Time: 17.400 ms
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't use gist for the trigram index either.